# how to build my Java app with OSv unikernel on Windows

Tags: unikernel

I'm new for OSv unikernel. Traying to get my head around it. I've followed 'Run Locally' (http://osv.io/run-locally/) page instructions, however it's not clear how to continue from there. I'd like to create a simple Java application and then build it on windows with Capstan and deploy and run it on VirtualBox, Google and Amazon platforms. Is there any straightforward instructions/tutorial that can make it easier? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the documentation on OSv's website are woefully out of date - it was created in a time where OSv was a commercial venture which placed a lot of emphasis on this website, and today, as a volunteer project, the github repository and mailing list (osv-dev in googlegroups.com) receives more attention. I suggest you ask OSv questions on that mailing list, instead of stack overflow.

Anyway, for your question, the Capstan project has examples how to build an image from some Java application:

https://github.com/cloudius-systems/capstan/blob/master/Documentation/RuntimeJava.md

If this doesn't work (I don't use Capstan myself, so I didn't check), please report it on the OSv mailing list, or Capstan's bug tracker. Thanks, and good luck.